Find specific text in the database and display the context of where that text is
I know there is the handy plugin Better Search Replace.
We're looking for something similar which will search the DB for specific text, but also display the context the text is in, e.g. the paragraph the text is in?
Does such a solution exist?
I haven't been able to find any such solution on Google.

For this I suggest you to use Search and Replace plugin which has Dry Run option under Tools > Search & Replace > Search & Replace, here we need to check the Dry Run checkbox.
In Dry Run we can find in which table we have that searched text so from that you can find the context of the searched text appearance.
Screenshot Link : https://ps.w.org/search-and-replace/assets/screenshot-5.png?rev=1339190
